# Wordpress - Load css file without ftp and admin rights

Tags: css, wordpress, styling

I'm facing a little problem, for a client of ours we need to modify the wordpress site. But they, and so do we, don't have the FTP access and no admin rights in Wordpress, so I can't install plugins or go to the theme editor.

Is there another way to add some css styling to the website? Also when I click on customize I don't have the option to add some css styling by...

Regards,

Comment: it is not possible to do any styling edits without Admin rights or without ftp account ! , if possible the website can be easy hackable :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to add custom css to your site, but your customer **need permission to access `wp-admin`.**

1. [Edit your css directly](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files)
2. Use plugin [Simple Custom Css](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/)

The another way is add an **external css** which your customer have permission to modify it. Example: Your website is http://example.com import a css file is http://customer.site/style.css.

Comment: @n00bly Simple Custom CSS allows to add code only to whole website.
Try http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js OR http://wordpress.org/plugins/css-injector